# How to unit test methods in windows form class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a developing a c# windows form application and I have a method that exists inside the main form class.

Imagine methodA as part of the main form class.

```
public void methodA() {
    A.someMethod();
    B.someMethod();

    // some more code

    if (someCondition) {
        // execute some code 
    }

    // initialize timer and set event handler for timer
    // run new thread 

    }

class A {
    someMethod() {...}
}

class B {
    someMethod() {...}
}
```

How would I run tests to test the branch logic of this methodA (isCondition)? since it involves initializing timer and running threads. Can i only verify the logic while doing system test ? I dont think it is possible to mock the timer and threading function.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can mock the timer. This is by creating a new interface, say, `ITimerWrapper` and implement it by using the concrete Timer class. Basically a wrapper of the Timer class. Then use that instead of the concrete Timer class you have.

Something in the tune of:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ITimerWrapper _timerWrapper;
    public Form1(ITimerWrapper timerWrapper)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._timerWrapper = timerWrapper; // of course this is done via dependency injection
        this._timerWrapper.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // now you can mock this interface

        this._timerWrapper.AddTickHandler(this.Tick_Event);
        this._timerWrapper.Start();
    }

    private void Tick_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("tick tock");
    }
}

public interface ITimerWrapper
{
    void AddTickHandler(EventHandler eventHandler);
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    int Interval { get; set; }
}
public class TimerWrapper : ITimerWrapper
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public TimerWrapper()
    {
        this._timer = new Timer();
    }

    public int Interval
    {
        get
        {
            return this._timer.Interval;
        }
        set
        {
            this._timer.Interval = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddTickHandler(EventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        this._timer.Tick += eventHandler;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this._timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this._timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Then for the spinning of a new thread, that's also testable by doing the same thing.

Bottomline is to have an interface to separate concerns and mock the interface on your unit test.

Comment: There is just one thing to note when bridging out all dependencies behind interfaces to enable TDD. You'll end up wrapping everything (DateTime, Environment, Timer, ..) which leads to high complexity in dependencies.

Comment: It seems that all the dependencies will have to be an interface class ?

Comment: @dfhwze, it will not lead in high complexity, it will lead in explicit and well documented(executable documentation) dependencies of the class/form you working with. On other side UI(WindowsForms) can be considered as entry point of your application and could/should be tested without mocking dependencies. For example framework for testing Winforms: https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GettingStarted/

Comment: @calveeen, No, mock only dependencies which makes your tests slow (database, file system, web services), very very very complicated to setup or inconsistent(time dependent).